# MySQL Database refusing connection to user with USAGE privileges

Tags: mysql, permissions, localhost

I have a user 'salesman'@'%' trying to connect to my database with USAGE privileges on `*.*`, and SELECT privileges on one view within the database.

Whenever I try to *connect* to the database whether via an API connection string or MySQL CLI, I receive the error 1044 (so it isn't a password issue: Error 1045).

`(1044, "Access denied for user 'salesman'@'%' to database 'northwind'")` from the API

`ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'salesman'@'%' to database 'northwind'` from the CLI.

I do not have user '' on my users, nor is localhost proving to be an issue (changing the username to localhost on the original create user and grant statements doesn't do anything). I have checked every question and bug report I could find and there are no relevant or working answers.